# Why would changing a copied element in an array affect the original element?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I tried to add a modified element in an array:

```
mm = Array.new
mm.push({'a' => 1})  
mm.unshift(mm[0])
mm[0]['b'] = 2
mm #=> [{'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}, {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}]
```

What I expected was:

```
mm #=> [{'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}, {'a' => 1}]
```

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: What is actually cloned?

Comment: You tagged the question with `clone`, but didn't use it. Using `clone` could give you the expected result.

Comment: Hint: `mm.unshift(mm[0].clone)`

Comment: Got the same result if change mm[0]['b'] = 2 to mm[1]['b'] = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect the variables to be referenced by value. In ruby, that’s not true. Everything is referenced by reference. To simplify,

```
▶ h = { a: 1 }
#⇒ { :a => 1 }
▶ h_another_ref = h
#⇒ { :a => 1 }
▶ h_another_ref[:b] = 42
▶ h
#⇒ { :a => 1, :b => 42 }
```

Here, both `h` and `h_another_ref` **refer to the same object**.

To achieve the desired behaviour, you might actually `clone` the object ([`Object#dup` or `Object#clone`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-dup)):

```
▶ h = { a: 1 }
#⇒ { :a => 1 }
#                   ⇓⇓⇓⇓
▶ h_another_inst = h.dup
#⇒ { :a => 1 }
▶ h_another_inst[:b] = 42
▶ h
#⇒ { :a => 1 }
▶ h_another_inst
#⇒ { :a => 1, :b => 42 }
```

Comment: I am not sure if your metaphor helps understanding the problem.

Comment: Me neither. Let’s wait for OP’s opinion.

Comment: I think it's misleading, changing one phone number doesn't change the other.

Comment: Agreed and have it removed.

Answer (score 1):

You modified `mm[0]`, which is the same hash instance as `mm[1]`. It is wrong to expect that `mm[0]` is modified without `mm[1]` being modified.